# MacOS Network Extensions equivalent to Kernel extensions?

Tags: macos, kernel-extension, networkextension, macos-system-extension

With the release of Big Sur - Network Kernel extensions are now officially inaccessible. However I cannot find the equivalent functionality I need in the new Network Extensions API.

In my NKE (network kernel extension) - i was able to control the routing of packets in a specific application by hooking socket binds and/or rewriting the source IP of outgoing packets for that application. Doing this i could control which interface those packets went through for that application (so called split tunneling).

I cannot see how to do something similar to this with the new APIs. Do the new APIs provide for this use-case? is it possible?

Comment: If you haven't already, I suggest getting in touch with Apple directly. (Feedback assistant & DTS TSI) Apple asked all users of NKEs to file Enhancement Request FBs for any functionality being actively used in NKEs but not available in NEs back at WWDC 2018 and again at 2019 I think but better late than never I guess. (Obviously there's a decent chance you did file but got ignored; you can still try a TSI just in case there's some solution.)